# library undef issue running rebar3 release

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I'm having a strange issue that I can't, for the life of me, figure out. I have a rebar3 app that I have generated a release from. If I run the app using `rebar3 shell` it runs fine, but if I run the release script with `_build/prod/rel/app_name/bin/app_name` it starts but fails when the code goes to start lager. When it attempts to run `lager:start` it returns an undef which results in the app terminating. I've scoured through every aspect of the app configuration and can't find anything that points to why this is not working. Any one have any insights?

rebar.conf

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [
    {ranch, {git, "https://github.com/ninenines/ranch.git", {tag, "1.4.0"}}},
    {lager, {git, "https://github.com/erlang-lager/lager.git", {tag, "3.5.1"}}},
    {mongodb, {git, "https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang.git", {tag, "v3.0.2"}}},
    {eredis, {git, "https://github.com/wooga/eredis.git", {tag, "v1.1.0"}}}
       ]}.

{relx, [
    {release, { tyranny_authservice, "0.1.0" }, [tyranny_authservice, sasl] },
        {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
        {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"},
        {dev_mode, false},
        {include_erts, true},
        {extended_start_script, true}
       ]
}.

{profiles, [
        {prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                          {include_erts, true},
                                {include_src, false}]}]
            }]
}.

{plugins, [rebar3_hex]}.

{erl_opts, [
        {parse_transform, lager_transform}
  ]}.
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out the issue without rebar.config file. Can you represent it?

Comment: The rebar.conf is rather standard. I added it to the question.

Comment: I am not sure becuase I have no access to whole code, but I guess you do not include lager as depended application to tyranny_authservice.app.src like this: {applications, [kernel, stdlib, lager]}

Comment: another option is to add the {included_applications, [lager]} in application resource file .app.src

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to include lager as depended application to tyranny_authservice.app.src like this:

   {applications, [kernel, stdlib, lager]}.
2. Another option is to add the

   {included_applications, [lager]}

in application resource file tyranny_authservice.app.src